# Comparing dates between arrays given EOM date

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, date

**Scenario:** This question is connected to a previous question of mine (the answer worked, but this other method of doing it still intrigues me, because it should, in theory, work). I am trying to compare data in 2 worksheets. Based on the date, I put the data from one sheet into another.

**Explanation:** One of my sheets have monthly data (EOM) while the other has daily data (working days); both have the same column items. Only the dates are relevant from my daily arrays (the other data in it is irrelevant). Which the code I have so far, I make those sets of dates into arrays, then I loop through both: get the first monthly date, then check if the first daily date is both >= to it, and <= to the last day of the next month minus 1 (for example, if monthly date is 31/12/2010, if checks if the daily date is >= to 31/12/2010 and <= 30/01/2011). In case the date fulfills the criteria, I paste the data from the monthly array into that row of the daily array, and so on.

**Problem:** For some reason I can't seem to find out, the code runs, but pastes the data improperly (for example, it pastes the data from the first monthly date into all the columns of the daily data (which comprise more than 5 years).

**Question:** Any idea on what is causing this problem?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim monthlydatesarray As Variant, monthlydataarray As Variant, dailydatesarray As Variant, dailydataarray As Variant
Dim xx As Long, monthlydaterow As Long, dailydaterow As Long, lastRowD As Long, lastRowM As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


lastRowD = Sheets("Bid").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("AMT").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row    

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "monthly" Then
        dailydataarray = wb.Sheets("daily").UsedRange
        dailydatesarray = wb.Sheets("daily").Range("A1:A" & lastRowD)
        monthlydatesarray = wb.Sheets("monthly").Range("A1:A" & lastRowM)
        monthlydataarray = wb.Sheets("monthly").UsedRange

        'if date matches, use the data values
        For monthlydaterow = 2 To UBound(monthlydatesarray)
            For dailydaterow = 2 To UBound(dailydatesarray)
                If dailydaterow = 2 And monthlydaterow = 2 Then
                    If dailydatesarray(dailydaterow, 1) >= monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1) And dailydatesarray(dailydaterow, 1) <= DateSerial(Year(monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1)), Month(monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1)) + 2, -1) Then
                        For xx = 2 To UBound(dailydataarray, 2)
                            dailydataarray(dailydaterow, xx) = monthlydataarray(monthlydaterow, xx)
                        Next xx
                    End If
                Else
                    If dailydatesarray(dailydaterow, 1) >= monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1) And dailydatesarray(dailydaterow, 1) <= DateSerial(Year(monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1)), Month(monthlydatesarray(monthlydaterow, 1)) + 2, -1) Then
                        For xx = 2 To UBound(dailydataarray, 2)
                            dailydataarray(dailydaterow, xx) = monthlydataarray(monthlydaterow, xx)
                        Next xx
                    End If
                End If
            Next dailydaterow
        Next monthlydaterow

        'wb.Sheets("test").Clear
        wb.Sheets("test").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dailydataarray, 1), UBound(dailydataarray, 2)) = dailydataarray
        ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    End If

Next ws
End Sub
```

**Data Example:**

```
Monthly date:
            Item 1      Item 2
2012.05.31  0           499285000
2012.06.28  0           499285000
2012.07.31  400000000   296891000
2012.08.30  400000000   296891000

Daily date:
            Item 1      Item 2
31.05.2012
01.06.2012
02.06.2012
03.06.2012
04.06.2012
05.06.2012
06.06.2012
07.06.2012
08.06.2012
09.06.2012
10.06.2012
11.06.2012
12.06.2012
13.06.2012
14.06.2012
15.06.2012
16.06.2012
17.06.2012
18.06.2012
19.06.2012
20.06.2012
21.06.2012
22.06.2012
23.06.2012
24.06.2012
25.06.2012
26.06.2012
27.06.2012
28.06.2012
29.06.2012
30.06.2012
01.07.2012
02.07.2012
03.07.2012
04.07.2012
05.07.2012
06.07.2012
07.07.2012
08.07.2012
09.07.2012
10.07.2012
11.07.2012
12.07.2012
13.07.2012
14.07.2012
15.07.2012
16.07.2012
17.07.2012
18.07.2012
19.07.2012
20.07.2012
21.07.2012
22.07.2012
23.07.2012
24.07.2012
25.07.2012
26.07.2012
27.07.2012
28.07.2012
29.07.2012
30.07.2012
31.07.2012
01.08.2012
02.08.2012
03.08.2012
04.08.2012
05.08.2012
06.08.2012
07.08.2012
08.08.2012
09.08.2012
10.08.2012
11.08.2012
12.08.2012
13.08.2012
14.08.2012
15.08.2012
16.08.2012
17.08.2012
18.08.2012
19.08.2012
20.08.2012
21.08.2012
22.08.2012
23.08.2012
24.08.2012
25.08.2012
26.08.2012
27.08.2012
28.08.2012
29.08.2012

Result arrays of the current code (relevant part):
            Item 1      Item 2
31.05.2012  0           499285000
01.06.2012  0           499285000
02.06.2012  0           499285000
03.06.2012  0           499285000
04.06.2012  0           499285000
05.06.2012  0           499285000
06.06.2012  0           499285000
07.06.2012  0           499285000
08.06.2012  0           499285000
09.06.2012  0           499285000
10.06.2012  0           499285000
11.06.2012  0           499285000
12.06.2012  0           499285000
13.06.2012  0           499285000
14.06.2012  0           499285000
15.06.2012  0           499285000
16.06.2012  0           499285000
17.06.2012  0           499285000
18.06.2012  0           499285000
19.06.2012  0           499285000
20.06.2012  0           499285000
21.06.2012  0           499285000
22.06.2012  0           499285000
23.06.2012  0           499285000
24.06.2012  0           499285000
25.06.2012  0           499285000
26.06.2012  0           499285000
27.06.2012  0           499285000
28.06.2012  0           499285000
29.06.2012  0           499285000
30.06.2012  0           499285000
01.07.2012  0           499285000
02.07.2012  0           499285000
03.07.2012  0           499285000
04.07.2012  0           499285000
05.07.2012  0           499285000
06.07.2012  0           499285000
07.07.2012  0           499285000
08.07.2012  0           499285000
09.07.2012  0           499285000
10.07.2012  0           499285000
11.07.2012  0           499285000
12.07.2012  0           499285000
13.07.2012  0           499285000
14.07.2012  0           499285000
15.07.2012  0           499285000
16.07.2012  0           499285000
17.07.2012  0           499285000
18.07.2012  0           499285000
19.07.2012  0           499285000
20.07.2012  0           499285000
21.07.2012  0           499285000
22.07.2012  0           499285000
23.07.2012  0           499285000
24.07.2012  0           499285000
25.07.2012  0           499285000
26.07.2012  0           499285000
27.07.2012  0           499285000
28.07.2012  0           499285000
29.07.2012  0           499285000
30.07.2012  0           499285000
31.07.2012  0           499285000
01.08.2012  0           499285000
02.08.2012  0           499285000
03.08.2012  0           499285000
04.08.2012  0           499285000
05.08.2012  0           499285000
06.08.2012  0           499285000
07.08.2012  0           499285000
08.08.2012  0           499285000
09.08.2012  0           499285000
10.08.2012  0           499285000
11.08.2012  0           499285000
12.08.2012  0           499285000
13.08.2012  0           499285000
14.08.2012  0           499285000
15.08.2012  0           499285000
16.08.2012  0           499285000
17.08.2012  0           499285000
18.08.2012  0           499285000
19.08.2012  0           499285000
20.08.2012  0           499285000
21.08.2012  0           499285000
22.08.2012  0           499285000
23.08.2012  0           499285000
24.08.2012  0           499285000
25.08.2012  0           499285000
26.08.2012  0           499285000
27.08.2012  0           499285000
28.08.2012  0           499285000
29.08.2012  0           499285000
30.08.2012  0           499285000
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot illustrating the wrong resuls?

Comment: @SJR Added in the end of question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the date comparison, with a assumed date formatting in Excel, you just need to compare the year and the month, such that:

```
Dim DM as Long, DD as Long, MM as Long, MD as Long, YM as Long, YD as Long, i as Long, j as Long. lrM as Long, lrD as Long
lrM = Sheets("Monthly").Cells(Sheets("Monthly").Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row
lrD = Sheets("Daily").Cells(Sheets("Daily").Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row
For i = 2 to lrM Step 1
    For j = lrD to 2 Step -1 'Assumes you're pasting into the Daily sheet
        DM = Day(Sheets("Monthly").Cells(i,1).Value) 'day of cell in monthly sheet
        MM = Month(Sheets("Monthly").Cells(i,1).Value) 'month of cell in monthly sheet
        YM = Year(Sheets("Monthly").Cells(i,1).Value) 'year of cell in monthly sheet
        DD = Day(Sheets("Daily").Cells(j,1).Value) 'day of cell in daily sheet
        MD = Month(Sheets("Daily").Cells(j,1).Value) 'month of cell in daily sheet
        YD = Year(Sheets("Daily").Cells(j,1).Value) 'year of cell in daily sheet
        If MM = MD And YM = YD And DD < DM And DD >= 1 Then
            'Do something...
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

If you don't have date formatting, you will need to use Right() & Left() to find the desired values in the string so you can compare, e.g.:

```
Left(Sheets("Monthly").Cells(i,1),4) = Right(Sheets("Daily").Cells(j,1),4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Couple of comments: first I tried exactly what you suggested at first, but since I have to fill the next month until the previous to last working day, just comparing year and month did not handle. Second: Very nice idea to check for left and right parts of the cell contents, but the issue is, this code will be used in computers with different time formats, so, in one the date might be 2011-12-31, and in another it might be 12-31-2011, and so on, which complicates the usage of LEFT and RIGHT.

Comment: @DGMS89 Sorry, after I edited the code section, I didn't change the words preceding it... I do a comparison for days as well, though I only took into account first day of the month to the day preceding the last day of the month, not the last business day.  That could be assessed with using Application.Worksheetfunction.Weekday() to return if it's, say, Friday... assess the last day of the month first, then you should be in a position to determine what day of the week (and day# in the month) you should be ending your search range.

Comment: @DGMS89 Regarding the date format, why not fix the dateformat of the column, first, e.g., Sheets().Range().NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"?

Comment: Indeed, I also did that, but trying to use the Workday function, but still go to the same problem. Also, when you compare: "If MM = MD And YM = YD And DD < DM And DD >= 1 Then" the month will only be the same for the first daily date, after that, the daily date will have the month +1, which is essentially what I did in my own code. And regarding the date format, yes I also tried doing that, but still get incompatibility problems arisen from different region formats (especially when for some reason, my source dates are changed to text).

Comment: I believe your code would have the same result as mine with some modifications to account for the date, but as from the OP, I already have a functional version of this procedure (from a previous question). My objective was try to understand what is the problem with the code I wrote, since, in theory, it should work.